# UIView drawRect: when you draw a line, the rect area will be clear so the previous drawing is gone

Tags: uiview, drawing, cgcontext, drawrect

It is quite hard to tell so I upload an image to show my problem: http://i42.tinypic.com/2eezamo.jpg

Basically in drawRect, I will draw the line from touchesMoved as finger touches and I will call "needsDisplayInRect" for redraw. But I found that the first line is done, the second line will clear the rect part, so some previouse drawing is gone.

Here is my implementation:

```
enter code here

-(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
//[super drawRect: rect];
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[self drawSquiggle:squiggle at:rect inContext:context];
}

- (void)drawSquiggle:(Squiggle *)squiggle at:(CGRect) rect inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{   

CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeMultiply);
UIColor *squiggleColor = squiggle.strokeColor; // get squiggle's color
CGColorRef colorRef = [squiggleColor CGColor]; // get the CGColor
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, colorRef);        

NSMutableArray *points = [squiggle points]; // get points from squiggle
// retrieve the NSValue object and store the value in firstPoint
CGPoint firstPoint; // declare a CGPoint
[[points objectAtIndex:0] getValue:&firstPoint];
// move to the point
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, firstPoint.x, firstPoint.y);
// draw a line from each point to the next in order

for (int i = 1; i < [points count]; i++)
{
    NSValue *value = [points objectAtIndex:i]; // get the next value
    CGPoint point; // declare a new point
    [value getValue:&point]; // store the value in point

    // draw a line to the new point
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);
} // end for
CGContextStrokePath(context); 
}
```

---

I try to implement this but seems it doesn't work as my expected.
I have implemented a view to draw an square every time setNeedsDisplay is called on the view. I put CGImageRef image and CGBitmapContextRef context into ivar and allocate them when the view inits.

```
#import "View.h"


@implementation View


#define bitsPerComponent 8
#define bitsPerPixel 4*bitsPerComponent
#define bytesPerPixel 4


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
    lastPoint = CGPointMake(50, 50);
    size_t width = frame.size.width;
    size_t height = frame.size.height;

    CFMutableDataRef data = CFDataCreateMutable( NULL , width * height * bytesPerPixel );  
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData( data );
    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    /*CGImageRef - ivar */ image = CGImageCreate(width, height, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, width*bytesPerPixel, colorspace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast, provider, NULL, NO, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    /*CGBitmapContextRef - ivar */ context = CGBitmapContextCreate(CFDataGetMutableBytePtr(data), width, height, bitsPerComponent, width*bytesPerPixel , colorspace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

    CFRelease( data ); // retained by provider I think
    CGDataProviderRelease( provider ); // retained by image
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
}
return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
NSLog(@"test");
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]);
CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y, 100, 100));
lastPoint = CGPointMake( ((int)lastPoint.x+50) % 380 , ((int)lastPoint.y+50) % 220 );
CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100),image);
}

- (void)dealloc {
[super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The graphics context returned by `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext` in `drawRect:` is owned by the system and cleared at the start of a drawing pass.  Create your own `CGContext` to record your drawing and render it to the `drawRect:` context as needed.

Create a paired `CGBitmapContext` and `CGImage` that refer to the same `CGDataProvider` and have the same size, color space and other properties.  Draw into that context when and how you see fit, then in `drawRect:` use `CGContextDrawImage` to display it.

Or if you are just doing a series of lines, you can build a `CGMutablePath` and render it to the system context.

Edit:

Look at `CGImageCreate` and `CGBitmapContextCreate` in their respective header files.  Most of the arguments are the same.  The bitmap context expects a raw data pointer, while the image expects a CGDataProvider.  Here is a rough sketch of what the code would look like.  In the end you can draw into the context then use the image to render into another context.

```
size_t width = 400;
size_t height = 300;
CFMutableDataRef data = CFDataCreateMutable( NULL , width * height * 4 ); // 4 is bytes per pixel
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData( data );
CGImageRef image = CGImageCreate( width , height , ... , provider , ... );
CGBitmapContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate( CFDataGetMutableBytePtr( data ) , width , height , ... );
CFRelease( data ); // retained by provider I think
CGDataProviderRelease( provider ); // retained by image
```

There are a lot of blanks to fill in, but this should get you started.  You could use malloc instead of CFData for the buffer.

Comment: I guess I've got your idea. But I am not sure about CGDataProvider and is there example code for that?

Comment: I have an implementation but it doesn't work as my expected. I guess my understanding is still on the wrong way? I have posted the code would you mind checking it?